# Automatic linebreak knitr xtable (R/Latex)

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I'm trying to do a `xtable` with long sentences at each row in my PDF document generated with `knitr`.

I tried that :

```
<<echo=F,results="asis",command=NA>>=
df<-c("This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long line",
"Another very very very very very very very very very very very long line")
df<-as.data.frame(df)
xtab <- xtable(df)
print.xtable(xtab,sanitize.text.function=function(x){x})
@
```

But my result is :

[image]

As you can see. My xtable overflow the page because my lines are too long. Can someone help me ?

PS : I can't use `{tabular}` because the length of my data frame depend of a shiny app user's input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the align function:

```
<<echo=FALSE,results=tex>>=
library(xtable)
df<-c("This is a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long line",
"Another very very very very very very very very very very very long line")
df<-as.data.frame(df)
xtab <- xtable(df)
align(xtab) <- "|lp{6cm}|"
print.xtable(xtab,sanitize.text.function=function(x){x})
@
```

You can use it to change the column alignment like you would for any other LaTeX table. These resources may be helpful to you:

1. [xtable gallery](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf)
2. [LaTeX Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX)

Comment: You rock ! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Smich7 Welcome to StackOverflow! I noticed you have not accepted any of the answers you have been given on this site. If an answer solves your problem you should click the check mark (it will turn green). If you continue to not accept answers people will be less inclined to answer your questions. Happy coding.

Comment: Excuse me I do that now !